# Unable to retrieve the text data into data frame after cleanup in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked here but I still believe my task is more complex.
I read a CSV file with 3 text columns into a data frame. I used `tm` package to clean the text data. I used the below code:

```
con_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(my_con$Verba)) 
corpus_clean <- tm_map(con_corpus, tolower)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removePunctuation)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, trim)
```

Now my worry is how to do clean the data in all 3 cloumns at a time.
Second is, how to convert this corpus data into dataframe so that I can see whether all the data that I have imported into R is cleaned up successfully.

Comment: Thanks Majid for the information. I have corrected the code prep_fun = function(x) {
  x %>% 
    # make text lower case
    str_to_lower %>% 
    # remove non-alphanumeric symbols
    str_replace_all("[^[:alnum:]]", " ") %>% 
    # collapse multiple spaces
    str_replace_all("\\s+", " ") %>% 
    str_trim(side = c("both", "left", "right")) %>% 
    strsplit(" ") %>% 
    lapply(sort) %>% 
    sapply(paste, collapse=" ")
}

Answer (score 0):

I would bring all text into one column before starting to clean it:

#### some sample data

Usually, it's easier to demonstrate a problem when you provide some data which looks like yours. I use random text to simulate what I think your data looks like.

```r
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_con <- data.frame(
  col1 = stri_rand_lipsum(nparagraphs = 3, start_lipsum = FALSE),
  col2 = stri_rand_lipsum(nparagraphs = 3, start_lipsum = FALSE),
  col3 = stri_rand_lipsum(nparagraphs = 3, start_lipsum = FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

#### data preparation

Two simple transformations to get the data into a more usable format. Check out `?mutate` from `dplyr` and `?pivot_longer` from `tidyr` if you are not familiar with the commands.

```r
    # add id and use tidyr to get text in one column
my_con_clean <- my_con %>% 
  mutate(id = seq_along(col1)) %>% # add id column to data.frame
  pivot_longer(col1:col3, "column", values_to = "Verba")
my_con_clean
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>      id column Verba                                                       
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>                                                       
#> 1     1 col1   Praesent dignissim fames lectus nec enim lacus sem aenean t…
#> 2     1 col2   Cubilia per fringilla. At ante, vulputate et morbi, tortor.…
#> 3     1 col3   Nisi duis gravida egestas ipsum maximus metus. Eget eget pr…
#> 4     2 col1   Elit purus suspendisse scelerisque diam sapien, nullam, int…
#> 5     2 col2   Purus nunc sit et, tortor a. Porttitor maecenas libero viva…
#> 6     2 col3   Urna sed amet elementum faucibus himenaeos urna elit at et.…
#> 7     3 col1   Massa ac ligula ut nunc nam tincidunt. Amet in, in proin od…
#> 8     3 col2   Duis volutpat, bibendum. Turpis faucibus vulputate velit ri…
#> 9     3 col3   Sed aenean eu eros arcu parturient vestibulum justo congue …
```

#### Now you can use the same pipeline as before but on the whole text

```r
con_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(my_con$Verba)) 
corpus_clean <- tm_map(con_corpus, tolower)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removePunctuation)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
# corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, trim)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code for this purpose.

```
prep_fun = function(x) {
  x %>% 
    # make text lower case
    str_to_lower %>% 
    # remove non-alphanumeric symbols
    str_replace_all("[^[:alnum:]]", " ") %>% 
    # collapse multiple spaces
    str_replace_all("\\s+", " ") %>% 
    str_trim(side = c("both", "left", "right")) %>% 
    strsplit(" ") %>% 
    lapply(sort) %>% 
    sapply(paste, collapse=" ")
}
```

Since I have only 3 columns I am applying this function one column at a time.